# adding a sms api along with wooCommerce E-mail sending

Tags: php, wordpress, sendmail, woocommerce, sms-gateway

I am developing a SMS gateway for my E-Commerce website and I am using Woo Commerce plugin in the Website. I have purchased SMS API from www.sms19.info. So, i want to use that api to send sms notification of status of order booked by customer and more even i want to edit the e-mail format being sent. To edit the e-mail format i tried editing

> classes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-note.php

file of woo Commerce but nothing changed in output.

**Website Link:**
[aamazedeals.com](http://www.aamazedeals.com)

i have attached the email format being sent as well

http://s28.postimg.org/upo7jfoz1/Untitled_1.jpg

so, please help me that where should i write the code for sms api for sending the sms notification along with the e-mail notification being sent.
I am stuck with this issue from last 3 days please help me out.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: You can code it in the same file. But remember, that's not update friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly edit your file and after or before this line `$this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );` you can add your sms sending function like

```
$this->sendSMS( $this->get_smsrecipient(), $this->get_smsfrom(), $this->get_smscontent());
```

*This is not update friendly*